# Accessing array variable using Module.exports

Tags: javascript

I have 2 files, 1 of them is the index.js and the other one is command file.

Command file contains:

```
module.exports.names = [
"language",
"localization",
"lang"
];
```

and in the index.js I try to access this array via:

```
const command = require(`./commands/command.js`);

command.names
```

but it says cannot read properties of undefined, when i try to console.log(command.names) it writes: **[ 'language', 'localization', 'lang' ]** and next line is **undefined**